# Does schroot allow configuration files in the home directory to be overwritten?

Tags: linux, chroot

When schroot is configured to mount /home, will packages installed inside the chroot overwrite the configuration files in $HOME?

For example,  if a newer version of gconf2 is installed inside the chroot, will it overwrite $HOME/.gconf?  Is there a way to prevent this, while maintaining access to /home?

Comment: You can't have both filesystem isolation *and* filesystem sharing.

Comment: Would mounting the /home filesystem to a different schroot mount point do the trick ?

Answer (score 1):

When /home is mounted by schroot, all configuration files are placed in $HOME of the base install, irrespective of whether they belong to the schroot.

This can lead to configuration files being overwritten when two versions of a package are installed, one in the base install and the other in the schroot.

It's easy to alter the schroot setup so that its configuration files are placed in a different directory, as shown in the following example.

A schroot for wheezy-amd64 is located in /var/schroot/wheezy-amd64. This particular schroot is using the 'desktop' profile, hence its mount points are defined in /etc/schroot/desktop/fstab.

First, create a home directory for the user inside the schroot,

```
mkdir /var/schroot/wheezy-amd64/home/$USERNAME
```

Second, replace the following line in /etc/schroot/desktop/fstab,

```
/home          /home           none    rw,bind         0       0
```

with,

```
/home          /HOME           none    rw,bind         0       0
```

That's all!  It's also convenient to add an alias to ~/.bash_aliases in the base install,

```
alias wheezy64='schroot -c wheezy-amd64 `/bin/echo "-d $PWD" | /bin/grep "^-d[ ]*\/home" | sed "s/home/HOME/"`'
```

Inside the schroot, the user now sees two home directories:

- /home/$USERNAME is the schroot home directory.
- /HOME/$USERNAME is the home directory of the base install.

Comment: I would urge you to register your account so you don't lose your cookie again. Welcome to Super User!