# schroot Don't Share Home Directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chroot

I created a schroot recently (following the directions [here](http://wiki.winehq.org/WineOn64bit)), and it conveniently shares my (host) user home directory. That is, `/home/username` is the same in the chroot as outside the chroot.

Where is this behaviour configured ? How can I prevent this behaviour ?

I'm using Ubuntu desktop 12.04 64-bit, and schroot version info is

```
$ schroot --version
schroot (Debian sbuild) 1.4.25 (03 Feb 2012)
```

Comment: Is it the same folder both places we are talking about. Or what is the reason you want this behavior changed?

Comment: @DibloDk If I understand your first question, I think the answer is yes. `find /home/username` returns the same values whether I'm chrooted or not.

Comment: @DibloDk Oops, I guess `enter` sends the message. The reason I want it changed is for security. I have a chroot so that I can run programs (I'm currently running Windows programs using wine, so I truly don't trust them!) without as much risk to my system. I don't want the programs to have access to my home directory. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Yes I can see that my question is very unclear. I think I have understood you, but to just be safe. - The home path `/home/username` are this two different path or the same? :)

Comment: @DibloDk They refer to the same part of the disk, and, naturally, have the same contents, so I'll say they're the same :-)

Comment: I think this question is misplaced. It should be on Unix & Linux SE. How do I move it?

Comment: Hi try if this works. I have not had time to check it for you etc.. http://superuser.com/questions/457756/does-schroot-allow-configuration-files-in-the-home-directory-to-be-overwritten

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, `schroot` mount directories according to filesystem table file `/etc/schroot/default/fstab`.  You could comment the line start with `/home` so that schroot won't bind-mount the home directory.

You could also specify other filesystem table file by editing schroot conf file.  For example, if you add `setup.fstab=minimal/fstab` to the end of `/etc/schroot/chrood.d/[your chroot's].conf`, schroot would filesystem according to `/etc/schroot/minimal/fstab`.

Comment: Wow! A *big* welcome to Stack Overflow, and, thanks for the excellent answer. It was worth the year-and-an-half wait!

Answer (score 0):

Go into the host system (exit the chroot), and run mount. There, you should see where you home directory (and any others) are mounted into the chroot. Navigate to the destination directory and run `umount`. Something like this should work:

```
# umount $(mount | grep 'home.*precise' | awk '{print $3}')
```

where the grep pattern `home.*precise` is whatever matches the mount points you want to get rid of.

Comment: Unfortunately, the directory gets remounted later, and I'm not sure by what mechanism.